# UINavigationController Image Not centered on all Devices iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I have a `UINavigationController` image that I'm setting in the `App Delegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like this:

```
var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Header")!
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

The `Header` is the file in the `Assets.xcassets` with the 2x and 3x size images. I took out the 1x size because I read it was necessary and it wasn't making a difference either way. On an iPhone 6 the image is perfectly centered. While on a iPhone5 it's more to the right. When I put the above code in the viewDidLoad method in my file, I get a blank header.

I also tried resizing the image:

```
 var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Header")!
        image.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -260, 0, 0))
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

I even plugged in random numbers to see if anything changes and it doesn't.

Anyone have any idea what to do?

I referenced these links:

1. [UINavigationBar custom title position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992476/uinavigationbar-custom-title-position)
2. [Misaligned title in UINavigationBar since iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797807/misaligned-title-in-uinavigationbar-since-ios6)
3. [Center UIImage in UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490730/center-uiimage-in-uinavigationcontroller)

**UPDATE**

Centering the UIImage on the NavigationBar still doesn't work on the iPhone5.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code snip i have added in my app delegate.
which **works perfect for me**.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
        //Cutomize navigation bar
        let navBgImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "dummy_navigation_bg_image")!
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBgImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()];

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. It didn't move. Could there be a reason it not moving? Could it be a problem with the images?

Comment: just make sure you have proper image size, it should be not smaller (lets try 630x70 for 1x)

Comment: Ok yes, I see what you mean. This helps! 1 more question, do the images need to be the size of the UINavigationBar width depending on the screen size or it compiles/resizes based on the screen size?

Comment: I am glad that it was helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks. Any insight on the sizing part?

Comment: actually I'm still having a problem with the iPhone 5. I just noticed it. The iPhone 6 and the iPhone 6+ both work fine. But the iPhone 5 is the one giving me a problem. @RDC